# Avoid line breaking when using :before in CSS-formatted links

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I prepend images to certain links on my website using :before in CSS

```
a.ext:before {
    content:            url(./_img/ext.png);
}
```

Unfortunately it happens, that image and text are separated, if the is not much space.

[image: with line breaks]
vs.
[image: without line breaks]

It would be great, if the image is bound to the first word in the link (in HTML I'd use `&nbsp;` for that). Is something similar possible in CSS?

EDIT:
[image: Screenshot of JSFiddle]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a.ext {
    padding-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap; /* use this if you don't want the text to wrap */
}
a.ext:before {
    content: " ";
    background: url("https://www.azdes.gov/uploadedImages/icon_external_link.png") center center no-repeat transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 1.2em;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

[image]

Screenshots taken in Chrome 24 and Firefox 18.0.2. Need more in IE 7, 8, 9? :P

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/TXPJE/1/

Comment: At least in Firefox this does not work. If you make the window smaller, the image stays in the first line, while "External" goes to the second line,..

Comment: Wait. Lemme post a screenshot of the same fiddle.

Comment: @Sven Screenshots taken in Chrome 24 and Firefox 18.0.2. Need more in IE 7, 8, 9? :P

Comment: I added a screenshot to my Post, showing the JSFiddle when the window is small. The image does not wrap around together with "External", but the image is separated form "External" (at least in Firefox)

Comment: OKay. If you will have a use-case of width going that small, add `white-space: nowrap;` to it. :) See answer. :)

Comment: @Sven See the second screenshot. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you are trying to not let the image wrap under the text if the element is not wide enough to hold them.

A combination of overflow and white-space:nowrap might get the results you are looking for.

Comment: Well, wrapping should be possible within the link, but not between the first word an the "before"-image. If I set `white-space:nowrap`, this will also prevent long link-text to be wrapped around.